# Fancy string substitution for requirements to leave comments on the same padding on python

Tags: python, regex, substring

I write a handy tool for myself to leave comments in `pyproject.yaml` file in front of every requirement.

So it should look something like this.

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
django = "3.0.5"
djangorestframework = "3.11.0"              # Rest api [ https://www.django-rest-framework.org ]
psycopg2-binary = "2.8.4"                   # PostgreSQL driver
redis = "3.4.1"                             # The Python interface to the Redis key-value store
```

I know how to do it in a simple ugly way, but probably you can come with something sexy and clever?

I thought about:

```
new_text = re.sub('^(django[\s|=].*").*', r"\1                 # COMMENTS HERE", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Where instead of `django` will be package name of course... But it seems that there is no way to keep the same indentation because I can't get the length of the matched string there. And also I can't just use toml parser and rewrite file from scratch, because I want to keep existing comments which are not related to requirements.

I tried another approach. But I don't like it either.

```
poetry = parsed_toml['tool']['poetry']
    for dep_type in ('dependencies', 'dev-dependencies'):
        for dependency, version in poetry[dep_type].items():
            char_length = len(dependency + version)
            text = re.sub(f'^{dependency}.*{version}.*', f'{dependency} = "{version}" {" " * (45 - char_length)} # Comment', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

I also want to make this substitution with less possible iteration. So if you have any bright ideas, please share :)

Comment: Do you have a fixed character position for the beginning of the comment (e.g. position 45)  or do you expect them to be aligned with the comment on the next line ?

Comment: Comments must be on the fixed position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the length of the match by using a replacement function:

```
import re

text = '''\
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
django = "3.0.5"
djangorestframework = "3.11.0"              # Rest api [ https://www.django-rest-framework.org ]
psycopg2-binary = "2.8.4"                   # PostgreSQL driver
redis = "3.4.1"                             # The Python interface to the Redis key-value store
'''

def repl(m):
    return f'{m.group(1):44s}# COMMENTS HERE' # pad match out to 44 spaces before comment

text = re.sub('^(django[\s|=].*").*$', repl, text, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(text)
```

Output:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
django = "3.0.5"                            # COMMENTS HERE
djangorestframework = "3.11.0"              # Rest api [ https://www.django-rest-framework.org ]
psycopg2-binary = "2.8.4"                   # PostgreSQL driver
redis = "3.4.1"                             # The Python interface to the Redis key-value store
```

Comment: It looks great! Thank you 